# Writing a binary file a specific directory (pathway)

Tags: c

So I have code that generate a pseudo-random dungeon where rooms are rectangular and are made up of periods (`'.'`) while the hallways are made up of hash symbols (`'#'`), so when I run my program inside the terminal it will generate a dungeon within this terminal, but my goal now is to save this dungeon into a binary file that can be read back, essential saving the file and loading the file.

I have a specific pathway that the binary file needs to be saved and loaded which you can see in my code. I've written some back stuff so far, but I want to get someone's input if I'm going in the right direction with this, my question is how do I write my dungeon to a binary file? How is it that I read my dungeon to place it into binary file?  I'm also getting an error for my fopen statement, something about a binary operand statement, but I'm not sure what it means. Any advice is appreciated. I'm only going to post the code for the main function since that's where the loading and saving needs to happen, because I need to take command line arguments (`--save`, and `--load`), but if you need to see the whole code on how the dungeon generates I'll edit my post.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *ptr_path_home;
    char *directory;
    action_t action;

    ptr_path_home = getenv("HOME");
    directory = ".rlg327/";

    char *pathway = malloc(strlen(ptr_path_home) + strlen(directory) + 1);

    strcpy(pathway, ptr_path_home);
    strcat(pathway, directory);



    FILE *f;

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "--save") == 0)
    {
        action = write_binary;
    }

    if (action = write_binary)
    {
        f = fopen(pathway + "save.bin", "wb");
    }





    srand(time(NULL));
    createDungeon();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How the first paragraph is even relevant to the question?

Comment: *I'm also getting an error for my fopen statement, something about a binary operand statement*. Exactly what error are you getting?

Comment: `if (action = write_binary)` ==> `if (action == write_binary)`. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the question. In other words, you should practise the file i/o as an exercise.

Comment: `pathway + "save.bin"` is not doing what you think it is.  String concatenation is done using `strcat()` (which you use elsewhere) or something like `sprintf()` in C.  You need another language if you want to use `+` to join strings.

Comment: @Weather Vane Thanks for the advice, I think posting my code was unnecessary now that I think about it, because my question i have is how fwrite works, if you look at fwrite here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm You will notice that there is a string they have that they write, but in my case I want to write a dungeon that I print into the terminal into a bin file, does this mean that I have to store the dungeon in a very large array?

Comment: You can write to the file in pieces. You don't have to write everything at once. But if the entire game state is contained in a single `struct` you can write/read that `struct` to/from file in a single operation. It may not be a portable file though. One way to achieve that is to write the data as text.

Comment: @WeatherVane Okay I see, so I can store the number of rooms, their positions on the grid, and the hallways connecting them into this struct, and then read this struct into a binary file.

Comment: So long as no `struct` member is a pointer. If it is, you'll have to write the pointer's data to file too, and reconstruct a new pointer, and the data it is pointing to, when you load the game state.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't shown us the way you construct the dungeon and more
importantly the data structures you use, it's impossible to give you a
definitive answer to this. The comments have good suggestions for you.

I'd like to comment some of the things you've done in your `main` function. The
comment section is just to small for this.

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "--save") == 0)
{
    action = write_binary;
}
```

That is not incorrect per se, but you **should** check that there is an argument
at all. If the user didn't pass an argument, `argv[1]` will be `NULL` and your
program will crash. Better this way:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // argv[0] contains the name of the program,
    // if user executes your program like this:
    // ./yourprogram arg1 arg2 ... argv[0] will be
    // ./yourprogram
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [--save | --load]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // now is safe to do this
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "--save") == 0)
    {
        action = write_binary;
    }

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

If your program eventually takes more arguments, it's better to use a helper
function like [`getopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html). That makes life much easier.

```
if (action = write_binary)
{
    f = fopen(pathway + "save.bin", "wb");
}
```

There are 2 errors here:

1. `if(action = write_binary)` is not the same as `if(action == write_binary)`.
   The first one assigns the value of `write_binary` to `action`, it that value is
   an scalar (can be converted into a number) other than 0, then the condition is
   evaluated to `true`, `false` otherwise. If the value is not a scalar value, the
   compiler will print you an error message.

   The second `if` compares if `action` and `write_binary` are the same. That's
   most probably what you want.
2. `pathway + "save.bin"` does not concatenate strings. There is no native type
   for strings in C, like C++'s `std::string` or Python's `String`. In C a string
   is a sequence of bytes that ends with a byte of value `'\0'` (==0). You usually
   use a `char` array or a pointer to an array of `char`s for saving strings.

   A string literal (the one you write with quotes) returns in reality a pointer
   to a read-only location where a strings is saved. Note that

   ```
   const char *str = "hello";
   ```

   does not assign a string to `str`, it assigns the address where `"hello"` is
   stored. That's why you always need functions like `strcpy` to copy strings.

   You should do:

   ```
   int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
       ...
       FILE *f = NULL;

       char *ptr_path_home;
       const char *directory;
       const char *basename = "save.bin"

       ptr_path_home = getenv("HOME");
       directory = ".rlg327";

       char *pathway = malloc(strlen(ptr_path_home) + strlen(directory) +
               strlen(basename) + 3);

       // +3 because you need 2 slashes and the 0-terminating byte

       sprintf(pathway, "%s/%s/%s", ptr_path_home, directory, basename);
       ...

       if(action == write_binary)
       {
           // save file
           f = fopen(pathway, "wb");
           if(f == NULL)
           {
               free(pathway);
               perror(pathway);
               return 1;
           }
           ...
           fclose(f);

       }

       free(pathway);
       return 0;
   }
   ```